# running 'msfconsole' command it throws error

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rubygems, termux, metasploit

In termux while  "Could not find activerecord-6.1.4.7 in any of the sources", I tried running 'gem install activerecord' but still after installing this gem, it shows again same error. Plz help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Delete the metasploit version already installed and install the official version of Metasploit from the official website according to the given procedure!

Metasploit Website :- [Metasploit.com](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Nightly-Installers)
[image]

And if this does not solve your problem then type these commands in terminal :-

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

After it's done again install the metasploit framework.

I hope this will solve your error.